# C++ приведение типов

Tags: c++

Читал статью на Хабре, наткнулся на участок кода:

```
    sockaddr_in servInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&servInfo, sizeof(servInfo));    
                    
    servInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servInfo.sin_addr = ip_to_num;  
    servInfo.sin_port = htons(1234);
    
    erStat = bind(ServSock, (sockaddr*)&servInfo, sizeof(servInfo));
```

и увидел тут приведение типов по C-style'лу и сразу задался вопросом, как было бы корреткно привести servInfo типа sockaddr_in, к типу sockaddr* в C++ style. Между ними, насколько я просмотрел нет наследования. В голову сразу пришел reinterpret_cast, но как-то не уверен. Просьба объяснить или разжевать этот момент, как было бы корректно провести тут приведение типов по C++ style cast!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: в функцию `bind` можно передавать указатель на разные структуры для ipv4/ipv6/unix/apple. Можно было-бы типом сделать `void*`, но история развития сложилась по другому. И типом сделали указатель на ненужную структуру.

Comment: @AlexGlebe разве не считается void* плохим тоном, ибо может терять информацию при приведениях или что-то в таком духе? и вопрос был немного в другом, как корректно приводить тип, по плюсовому касту. но все равно, спасиб за ответ!

Comment: функция `bind` внутри себя делает обратное преобразование на нужный тип `(тип)pointer` и это по стандарту даст правильный указатель. И вам желательно использовать скобочное преобразование. *кажется в плюсах это аналог `reinterpret_cast`*

Comment: imho С++-сные касты на практике не имеют особых преимуществ перед простым сишным кастом (если только вам не платят за количество символов в программе -)). Что же касается смысла структур sockaddr и sockaddr_in, то нужно рассматривать sockaddr как общий контейнер для структур адресов разных семейств. У всех таких структур первые 2 байта это sa_familly. В зависимости от их значения bind наложит структуру нужного типа на заданную память (путем каста указателя к требуемому типу) и будет использовать уже ее поля

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast` немного лучше по стилю, потому что показывает, что это не каст к родителю или что-то подобное.

С чисто практической точки зрения никакой разницы нет. Формально это в любом случае UB, потому что нарушение strict aliasing, но на практике, раз компилятор не видит тело библиотечной функции, то и сломать ничего не может (потому что должен предполагать, что та функция делает что-то легальное - например, `reinterpret_cast` обратно в правильный тип, и только потом разыменовывает).

Comment: немного не понял. то есть, тут реинтерпрет будет УБ?

Comment: `memcpy` -  тоже библиотечная функция, но компилятор знает про неё вообще всё. Прикрываться "незнанием" компилятора не годится.

Comment: @bellynya Да, но и сишный каст тоже. Это формальность, на практике и то и другое будет работать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat понял, спасибо. это считается дурным тоном занятие подобными приведениями, по идее?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy код не мой, но прислушаюсь)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Может это в отдельный ответ напишете? `sockaddr` ведь тоже не так прост, там flexible array member на конце.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat и да, то есть в подобных ситуациях, стоит использовать реинтерпрет, я правильно понял?

Comment: Ответ писать не буду. Вот почему. В [документации](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) прямо сказано что такое приведение правильное. Внутри bind делается обратное приведение. Но до этого приведения делается обращение к первому полю, которое UB. Я сдаюсь. (Справедливости ради, надо добавить что говорить про UB внутри bind неправильно. Эта функция может быть написана не на C вообще).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy у вас ссылка на документацию некорректная

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ссылка не туда. Но мануал как раз сижу читаю :) Про `memcpy` пример неудачный; я не видел, чтобы компиляторы что-то ломали ее оптимизацией.

Comment: Ссылку поправил.

Comment: @bellynya *"стоит использовать реинтерпрет, я правильно понял"* Как хотите. Имхо, немного лучше смотрится, но не намного. *"это считается дурным тоном занятие подобными приведениями"* Если бы bind писали вы сами, на С++ вместо С, то да, это было бы дурным тоном. Но если аж в мануале советуют так кастовать, то это ок.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Угу, UB надо избегать избирательно. Если начать глубоко копать, выяснится, что он вообще повсюду. :) (вспомнить тот же `std::launder`)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat понял, благодарю

Comment: Резюме: `reinterpret_cast` в нашем коде не UB (указатель у нас не разыменовывается). Внутри функции это мог бы быть UB, если бы она была написана на стандартом C. Но она может быть написана не C, или автор библиотеки убедился что машинный код делает то что нужно. То есть, `bind` написана вне стандарта C и ладно. Целиком программа корректная.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ну, вообще-то, strict-aliasing в случае одного указателя в параметрах функции (раздельно компилируемой) ничего сломать не сможет. Т.о. говорить про UB тут нет смысла

Comment: @avp Угу, я так и написал, что это чисто формальное UB.